# How i can fetch all data by latitude and longitude from wigle api

Tags: api, go

I wrote simple script to receive all data from wigle api using wigleapiv2, definitely this endpoint /api/v2/network/search. But I faced the problem, that I can receive only 1000 unique ssid's. I'm changing URL every iteration, and put in URL previous page's searchAfter. How can I fix it and receive all data from certain latitude and longitude?

Here an example of first iteration Uri (https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search?closestLat=12.9&closestLong=1.2&latrange1=1.9&latrange2=1.8&longrange1=1.2&longrange2=1.4)

And here an example of remaining iterations uris (https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search?closestLat=12.9&closestLong=1.2&latrange1=1.9&latrange2=1.8&longrange1=1.2&longrange2=1.4&searchAfter=1976621348&first=1). For every iteration I'm changing searchAfter and first.
It would be great id someone can say me where I'm doing wrong:)

I've tried to using only first or search after parameters, but it has the same result. One mark that I noticed, that when I'm using only searchAfter param I can receive only 100 unique ssids, but when I'm using both (searchAfter and first) I can receive 1000 unique ssids.

Here my main.go code

```
var (
        wg          = sync.WaitGroup{}
    receiveResp = make(chan []*response.WiFiNetworkWithLocation, 100)

)

func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()

    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    viper.SetConfigFile("config.json")
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error trying read from config: %w", err)
    }

    u := user.NewUser(viper.GetString("users.user.username"),   viper.GetString("users.user.password"))

    db, err := postgres.NewPG()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Cannot create postgres connection: %v", err)
    }

    postgres.WG.Add(1)
    go getResponse(u)

    go parseResponse(db)

    postgres.WG.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("Execution time: %v ", time.Since(startTime))
}

func getResponse(u *user.Creds) {
    url := fmt.Sprintf("%s?      closestLat=%s&closestLong=%s&latrange1=%s&latrange2=%s&longrange1=%s&longrange2=%s",
        viper.GetString("wigle.url"),
        viper.GetString("queries.closestLat"),
        viper.GetString("queries.closestLong"),
        viper.GetString("queries.latrange1"),
        viper.GetString("queries.latrange2"),
        viper.GetString("queries.longrange1"),
        viper.GetString("queries.longrange2"),
    )

    j := 0
    i := 0
    for {
         i++

    fmt.Println(url)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("")))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed wraps request: %v", err)

        continue
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth(u.Username, u.Password)

    c := http.Client{}
    resp, err := c.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed send request: %v", err)

        continue
    }

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed read response body: %v", err)

        continue
    }

    var r response.NetSearchResponse

    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &r); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed unmarshal: %v", err)

        continue
    }

    receiveResp <- r.Results

    fmt.Println(r.TotalResults, r.SearchAfter)

    if r.SearchAfter == "" {
        postgres.WG.Done()
        return
    }

    url = fmt.Sprintf("%s?  closestLat=%s&closestLong=%s&latrange1=%s&latrange2=%s&longrange1=%s&longrange2=%s&searchAfter=%s&first=%v"  ,
            viper.GetString("wigle.url"),
        viper.GetString("queries.closestLat"),
        viper.GetString("queries.closestLong"),
        viper.GetString("queries.latrange1"),
        viper.GetString("queries.latrange2"),
        viper.GetString("queries.longrange1"),
        viper.GetString("queries.longrange2"),
        r.SearchAfter,
        i,
    )
    j++

    fmt.Println(j)
}
```

```golang
func parseResponse(db *sql.DB) {
    for {
        select {
        case responses := <-receiveResp:
            clearResponses := make([]response.WiFiNetworkWithLocation, 0, len(responses))

            for _, val := range responses {
                clearResponses = append(clearResponses, *val)
            }
            postgres.WG.Add(1)
            go postgres.SaveToDB(db, "test", clearResponses)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"first" isn't a parameter in the WiGLE API; There's no path to increasing your query result size that way. https://api.wigle.net/swagger#/Network%20search%20and%20information%20tools/search_2 is the official, interactive documentation.

WiGLE implements per-account query limits - if you want to increase your daily limits, contact the admins at WiGLE-admin@wigle.net